# Convenient way to define lots of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my current code, I need to define a lot of lists and return them in a dictionary.

This alone takes up ~100 lines of code. It works, but I'm curious if there's a better way to write this code

```py
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
.
.
.

return {"list1": list1,
"list2": list2,
"list3": list3,
...
}
```

I first define ~40 lists, append them with data and return ~60-70 lists in a dictionary after some additional calculations (later I'm creating dataframes with this data).

This makes the code really bulky, so is there a way to "beautify" this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on why you are doing this, you may be able to use a very helpful class from `collections` called the `defaultdict`. This object operates like a dict, but also has a default return value when you call a key that does not exist.

That means you may be able to replace your code with:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
```

This means whenever you access a value, it will create an empty list if it was not there before. This lets you append to your lists as you were before:

```
data['list1'].append('your_value_here')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely some misconception of your code. If you repeat one action a lot, a for loop is always possible:

```
result = dict()
for k in range(1, 41):
    result["list"+str(k)] = []
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
{"list"+str(k):[] for k in range(1, 41)}
```

Then you need to figure out what your lists are supposed to contain.. because I don't get why you create all those empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for i in range(40):
    d["list"+str(i)] = []
```

Comment: Don't post code only answers. Provide some explanation.